# how to get absolute value without 'abs' function?

Tags: function, python-3.x

```
def my_abs(value):
"""Returns absolute value without using abs function"""
    if value < 5 :
        print(value * 1)
    else:
        print(value * -1)
print(my_abs(3.5))
```

that's my code so far but the quiz prints, for example -11.255 and 200.01 and wants the opposite for example it wants 11.255 back and -200.01

Answer (score 3):

What does `5` have to do with absolute value?

Following your logic:

```
def my_abs(value):
    """Returns absolute value without using abs function"""
    if value <= 0:
        return value * -1
    return value * 1

print(my_abs(-3.5))
>> 3.5
print(my_abs(3.5))
>> 3.5
```

Other, shorter solutions also exist and can be seen in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions so far don't take into account signed zeros. In all of them, an input of either 0.0 or -0.0 will result in -0.0.

Here is a simple and (as far as I see) correct solution:

```
def my_abs(value):
    return (value**2)**(0.5)
```

Comment: `result` will be same but it will return `float` value  even if values is `int`

Comment: Indeed, if that matters, that would need a little additional code (e.g. `if isinstance(value, int)` then `return int((value**2)**(0.5))` ).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for rational numbers would be

```
def my_abs(value):
    if value<0:
        return -value
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to check `if value < 5`?

Anyways, to replicate the abs function:

```
def my_abs(value):
    return value if value >=0 else -1 * value
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun one.
if (number < 0) returns a boolean but when you do math with it it's a 1 or 0. Below written as (a<0)

When the number is less than 0, we can get its positive value by adding 2 times the negative of itself. or just subtract itself twice written as (-a-a)

so when our condition fails it returns 0 which when multiplied by anything is zero so we don't add anything to our original number.

if our condition passes, we'll get a 2 times the positive so we can add to our original.

here's the code, the number you're trying to get absolute value is a in this case

```
a = a + (a<0) * (-a-a)
```

This runs slower than the built in abs() call.
I thought it was faster but it was buggy in my code when I timed it.
the fastest seem to be the if (a<0) then a = -a

Answer (score -2):

```
num = float(input("Enter any number: "))
if num < 0 :
    print("Here's the absolute value: ", num*-1)
elif num == 0 :
    print("Here's the absolute value: 0")
elif num > 0 :
    print("Here's the absolute value: ", num)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.