# How to find the absolute value of an integer or float in Python, without using libraries, division, square roots, conditions, or inbuilt functions

Tags: python

I wanted to know if it was possible to do such a thing in Python 3. Using abs() is of course not allowed. No importing is allowed as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587114/how-to-get-absolute-value-without-abs-function

Comment: Multiplication and subtraction allowed?

Comment: Does "inbuilt functions" include methods, or just builtins? What's left? Operators?

Comment: Does using `num ** 0.5` count as using a square root? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
{1e999: x, -1e999: -x}[x*1e999]
```

I'm serious. This works.

The `1e999` is interpreted as a float, but it overflows the available precision, so it's `inf`. But infinity can be positive or negative. By multiplying `x` with infinity, we can coerce it into one of two values based on its sign, without using a condition operator. Then we can select `x` or its negation from a lookup table.

It's equivalent to the following, but doesn't require the import:

```
from math import inf

{inf: x, -inf: -x}[x*inf]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the built-in classes (`int`, `str`, etc) to be built-in "functions". You could do something like the following

```
num.__class__(('%s' % num).lstrip('-'))
```

Convert the number to a string, strip the negative sign and then use the original numbers class to convert back

Comment: `__class__` was clever.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a string with a sign and slice off the first character. The `__class__` is not technically a method, so no methods.

```
x.__class__(f'{x:+}'[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the first character of the string representation is '-' and return the negation. But don't negate when you're wrong.

```
def abs(x):
    try:
        return {'-': -x}[f'{x}'[0]]
    except:
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Format a string to always include the sign and then look up its first character in a table.

```
{'-': -x, '+': x}[f'{x:+}'[0]]
```

Answer (score -1):

The `abs()` builtin just calls the `.__abs__()` method. No imports, no builtins, no conditions, no division, no square roots. And no `abs()`.

```
x.__abs__()
```